# Use path in ASN.1 Imports

Tags: asn.1

Since i couldn't find the answer anywhere, thought should probably ask it.

In `ASN.1` we use `IMPORTS` to import modules from *other* `ASN`. The syntax is of course as follows,

```
IMPORTS valuetag from eutra-def
```

My question is how to import it from the ASN that **does not** exist in the same folder. In other words how can i provide the path where eutra-def exist?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on your tools.  From an ASN.1 perspective, you are simply declaring that valuetag from module eutra-def may be legally referenced in this module.  ASN.1 doesn't care where or how that module is defined and doesn't give you any way to specify that.